# Connecting the collab to a Windows network drive

Tags: google-colaboratory, blender

First of all, I downloaded to the server on Hamachi, then joined the group, the pc sees the server (through hamachi, respectively). But when you try to connect a virtual disk, the server cannot find it. The goal was to use the server for Blender, or rather with Flamenco.